# JuMP 0.20 - How to get a relaxed solution using !optimize?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

In JuMP 0.18 we could do `solve(model, relaxation=true)`.

There isn't this option in `!optimize`, so how can I get a relaxed solution?

Comment: It seems there is no direct solution for now: https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl/issues/1611